# Exclude column from plot in pandas group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that contains 4 columns with a DateTimeIndex.  I have grouped the data by the 4th column and would like to print the grouped data.  However, each time I call df.mean().plot(), it plots the data of the column I used to group the data.  Is there a way to exclude this column from the plot?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cols2select = [col for col in df.columns.tolist() if col not in ['column_name_to_exclude']]
df[cols2select].plot()
```